# Python: Aborted (core dumped) while running FastAPI with uvicorn in Docker

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, fastapi, uvicorn

I have Python FastAPI backend app. I'm trying to run the docker image (dockerfile below) on our production environment where we run a lot of other (although not Python) containers without problems. After executing `uvicorn --port 8000 main:app` I can see the first few lines of uvicorn server initiating and then suddenly just message `Aborted (core dumped)`:

```
INFO:     Started server process [28]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Some `core` file is created in the working directory, I have found out it is somehow possible to find more details about the error after inspecting this file using `gdb` package, but I can't manage to install it inside the docker. After running uvicorn with command `python -X dev -m uvicorn main:app` I can see some more messages logged in the console:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/openapi/models.py:55: DeprecationWarning: `general_plain_validator_function` is deprecated, use `with_info_plain_validator_function` instead.
  return general_plain_validator_function(cls._validate)
/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic_core/core_schema.py:3898: DeprecationWarning: `general_plain_validator_function` is deprecated, use `with_info_plain_validator_function` instead.
  warnings.warn(
INFO:     Started server process [29]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
Executing <Task pending name='Task-1' coro=<Server.serve() running at /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py:78> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task.task_wakeup()] created at /usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/locks.py:210> cb=[run_until_complete.<locals>.done_cb()] created at /usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/runners.py:100> took 1.317 seconds
INFO:     Application startup complete.
Fatal Python error: Aborted

Current thread 0x00007fd36fcbfb80 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 160 in startup
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 78 in serve
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/runners.py", line 118 in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/runners.py", line 190 in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 61 in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 587 in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 416 in main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 783 in invoke
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1434 in invoke
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1078 in main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1157 in __call__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/__main__.py", line 4 in <module>
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88 in _run_code
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198 in _run_module_as_main

Extension modules: uvloop.loop, httptools.parser.parser, httptools.parser.url_parser, websockets.speedups (total: 4)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

This is the dockerfile I have been trying to use before:

```
FROM python:3.11
WORKDIR /app
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Install Poetry
RUN curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/install-poetry.py | POETRY_HOME=/opt/poetry python && \
    cd /usr/local/bin && \
    ln -s /opt/poetry/bin/poetry && \
    poetry config virtualenvs.create false

COPY . /app
RUN poetry install --no-root --no-dev

CMD uvicorn --port 8000 main:app
```

I have tried using different Python versions (3.11 + 3.10), I have also tried using different dockerfile and also running just a following simple script with one just FastAPI endpoint, to ensure that the error is not caused by my code. The same error happens while running this simple script:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def read_root():
    return {"message": "Hello, World!"}
```

I have also tried using different package manager, just simple pip (not poetry), with no changes.

This is another very simple dockerfile that I've tried to use with the simple script above (resulting in the same error - Aborted: (core dumped)):

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn:python3.11

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN printf 'fastapi>=0.98.0\npydantic>=2.0.0\nuvicorn>=0.23.2' >> ./requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r ./requirements.txt

CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

I have used `tail` there just to keep container running and be able to attach bash to it, because if I use `uvicorn`, the container keeps restarting.